# Filter bigram list from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I figured out a way to accomplish what I had wanted to do, so I am revising my original text. My solution works, but it is far from elegant or the most efficient way of solving the problem. What I would like to know now is a cleaner, shorter way that uses fewer lines of code to accomplish my desired tasks. The only thing that I can't figure out right now is how to get the date column in my ggplot to display more verbose information. My data has date stamps from 2014-2-2 through 2014-12-02. On my ggplot it only displays "Apr," "Jul," and "Oct." I would like the x-axis to have more dates on it. Here is my current approach along with a sample of the final dataframe:

```
selectedRows <- feedback[grep("top shelf", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows$keyword <- "top shelf"
selectedRows2 <- feedback[grep("silver haze", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows2$keyword <- "silver haze"
selectedRows3 <- feedback[grep("grade aaaa", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows3$keyword <- "grade aaaa"
selectedRows4 <- feedback[grep("top quality", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows4$keyword <- "top quality"
selectedRows5 <- feedback[grep("Purple Fruity", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows5$keyword <- "Purple Fruity"
selectedRows6 <- feedback[grep("highest grade", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows6$keyword <- "highest grade"
selectedRows7 <- feedback[grep("High quality", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows7$keyword <- "High quality"
selectedRows8 <- feedback[grep("free sample", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows8$keyword <- "free sample"
selectedRows9 <- feedback[grep("Exodus Cheese", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows9$keyword <- "Exodus Cheese"
selectedRows10 <- feedback[grep("limited time", feedback$product), ]
selectedRows10$keyword <- "limited time"
RAKE_keywords <- rbind(selectedRows, 
selectedRows2,selectedRows3,selectedRows4,
                   selectedRows5,selectedRows6,selectedRows7,selectedRows8,
                   selectedRows9,selectedRows10)


RAKE_keywords$date <- as.Date(RAKE_keywords$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
Date = ts(RAKE_keywords$keyword,c(2014,02),c(2017,12),1)

ggplot(data=RAKE_keywords,
   aes(x=date,y=keyword,fill=keyword)) +
  geom_tile()

head(RAKE_keywords)

   date           vendor      keyword   
2014-04-26 Charlie_Bartlett  top shelf
2014-09-22        KushDepot  top shelf
2014-05-06 Charlie_Bartlett  top shelf
2014-05-06 Charlie_Bartlett  top shelf
2014-10-06        KushDepot  top shelf
2014-02-02 Charlie_Bartlett  top shelf
```

[Example of ggplot output of final dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFdxC.jpg)

Comment: It will be helpful if you have a sample of your two dataframes.

Comment: In my original comments I left two screen captures of the two dataframes. The first is the original dataframe. The keywords were extracted from a column named "product." The second sample is the resulting top 10 keywords (bigrams) that were extracted using the RAKE algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really helpful. Include a sample in the text if the question (using head(), and preferably using dput()). It will drastically increase the likelihood you'll get a response.

Comment: I provided head() statements for both dataframes in the original comments. I also included dput() statements for the bigrams dataframe. There was far too much data produced by the feedback dput() command to include here. I am still relatively new to R and to machine learning, so please forgive the occasional missteps when I comment.

Comment: Can you post some reproducible example?

Comment: It would be handy to have a sample of your feedback data.frame where there are some records that should match with the bigrams. At the moment it would be guessing on how to join the tables. Also giving you the syntax is asking for a tutorial and that is against SO rules. Show what you have tried and where you get stuck.

Comment: Or you could provide some example of desirable output.

Comment: I added some code that I used to accomplish my desired task along with some output. I need to find a way to accomplish what I wrote in a smaller amount of code. I also need to plot my ggplot diagram with more verbose date column output on the x-axis. What I have posted here works, I just need to improve it.